# C# конструктор без параметров базового класса

Tags: c#, c#-faq

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int X;
    public BaseClass() { X = 1; }
}
public class Subclass : BaseClass
{
    public Subclass() { Console.WriteLine(X); } //1
}
```

Код взят из учебника и мне непонятно, почему конструктор базового класса тоже вызывается. Ведь мы не вызываем его через ":base"

Comment: данный конструктор вызывается по умолчанию. его не обязательно прописывать напрямую

Comment: а смысл ключевого слова base тогда?

Comment: с его помощью можно указать конкретный конструктор, если базовый класс имеет несколько, либо если в базовом классе отсутствует конструктор без параметров

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Базовый конструктор по умолчанию вызывается всегда, если он присутствует в базовом классе*. Стоит помнить, что конструктор по умолчанию генерируется всегда, если отсутствуют другие конструкторы.

Явный вызов базового конструктора через ключевое слово `base` нужен в том случае, когда у вас есть один или несколько конструкторов с параметрами, и вам нужно/вы хотите пробросить все или часть этих параметров в базовый класс, указав при этом конкретный конструктор базового класса:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string someParam)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ChildClass: BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass(string someParam, int someParam2)
        : base(someParam)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Вы также можете использовать его и в вашем случае, однако в этом нет нужды и компилятор это подскажет:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int X;
    public BaseClass() { X = 1; }
}

public class Subclass : BaseClass
{
    public Subclass()
        : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(X);
    }
}
```

---

*[существуют исключения](http://ideone.com/MiBekE): например, когда конструктор по умолчанию наследника вызывает конструктор с параметрами базового класса, используя `base()`

Comment: Первое предложение сомнительно. Если в наследнике нет конструктора по умолчанию, то конструктор базового класса по умолчанию будет вызван неявно.

Comment: @alexolut прочитайте второе предложение.

Comment: Второе предложение изменит смысл первого, или в чем посыл?

Comment: @alexolut посыл в том, что оно а) дополняет первое предложение, б) содержит то же самое уточнение, что вы написали.

Comment: То ли я Вас не понял, то ли Вы не поняли меня. Посмотрите [код](http://ideone.com/701HWc), конструктора по умолчанию в `D` нет, но при этом `B()` вызывается неявно.

Comment: @andreycha: Судя по всему, имелось в виду это: http://ideone.com/MiBekE: у наследника есть конструктор по умолчанию, но конструктор по умолчанию базового класса не вызывается.

Comment: @alexolut да, пишу одно, в уме держу другое. Спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Comment: @VladD а вот о таком кейсе я не подумал. Спасибо за замечание, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

При создании экземпляра класса наследника **всегда** вызывается конструктор базового класса.

[ключевое слово *base*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx#mt3) позволяет указать какой именно конструктор базового класса будет вызван.

При отсутствии указания, компилятор будет пытаться вызывать из базового класса конструктор без параметров, и если в базовом классе такой конструктор будет отсутствовать, то будет ошибка, о том, что базовый тип не содержит конструктора без параметров.

```
using System;

class B {
    public B(int i) {Console.WriteLine("Base non-default constructor");}
}

class D : B {
    public D(int i) {} // error CS1729: The type `B' does not contain a constructor that takes `0' arguments
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new D(42);
    }
}
```